# Does an exit relay also relays non-exit traffic?

Tags: relays, exit-relays, exit-policies

I would like to run an exit relay, but I don't want to deal with almost any abuse issues. So I figured to **only exit to hidden services.** If my understandings are right, the exit policy and the relay part of my `torrc` should look like this:

```
ExitRelay 1
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

But I would also like to **relay non-exit traffic, on the same machine.**

Is this possible?

Or do I have any misunderstandings, for example, am I already able to be the third hop to a hidden service even if I have `ExitRelay 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

As onion services "live" within the network, you don't need to be an exit to relay onion service traffic.

See https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/onion-services for details.

Exits are "only" needed for exiting to the clearnet.

Thank you for running any relay.

Comment: Thank you for answering my main question. I would still like to know that if I run an "actual" exit relay, do I relay any kind of non-exit traffic? My question might be quite unrealistic here, because exit relays are usually extremely busy just on exiting since there are relatively few of them.

Comment: As far as I know, an exit is just a normal relay which happens to have the exit flag (and so, permitting exit rules) as well.